# Get all options middle value only,with selected(desired) class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have drop down list which contain some values which is retrieved from database table, what I want is when click on button it should get only middle values of option tag but only those option tag whose class name is  'get_this' and leave those option if they don't have this class

Expected output:
value 1
value 3
value 4

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select  id="selectBox">
  <option class="get_this">text1   value 1    text1 </option>
  <option >text2   value 2    text2</option>
  <option class="get_this">text3   value 3    text3</option>
  <option class="get_this">text4   value 4    text4</option>
</select>

  <input type="submit" value="Get all options" class="get_options"/>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script>
  var array_values = [];
  $(".get_options").click( function (){

  var values = $.map($('#selectBox option'), function(ele) {

   array_values.push(ele.value);
});

  console.log(array_values);
  });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set the `.on('click'...` method on button.
- On `.each()` `.get_this` extract text with `.text()`
- Then `split()` the text string on every two consecutive spaces (you shouldn't use so many spaces it becomes problematic)
- We are left with an array from each `.get_this`.
- Extract the second string from each array by referencing index 1: `array[1]`
- Finally push each string into an empty array.

---

### Demo

```js
$('.get_options').on('click', function(e) {
  var result = [];
  $('.get_this').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var array = text.split(/\s{2,}/);
    result.push(`${array[1]}`);
  });
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <select id="selectBox">
    <option class="get_this">text1   value 1   text1 </option>
    <option>text2   value 2   text2</option>
    <option class="get_this">text3   value 3   text3</option>
    <option class="get_this">text4   value 4   text4</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Get all options" class="get_options" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you please explain me what is purpose of those slashes and 's{2}' var array = text.split(/\s{2,}/);

Comment: @Anonymous That's a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) which is like a pseudo-language used to match patterns in text. The two forward slashes `/`...`/` are the beginning and end of any regex literal. `\s` is a meta-sequence that represents one character of any type of space. `{2,}` is a qualitative that determines how many consecutive occurrences of `\s` there should be. `{2,}` means `2` and that comma `,` means `or more`. So basically it matches any 2 or more spaces.

Answer (score 2):

When value of an `<option>` tag needs to differ from its text content, you may want to specify a `value` attribute.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select  id="selectBox">
  <option class="get_this" value="value 1">text1   value 1    text1 </option>
  <option value="value 2">text2   value 2    text2</option>
  <option class="get_this" value="value 3">text3   value 3    text3</option>
  <option class="get_this" value="value 4">text4   value 4    text4</option>
</select>

  <input type="submit" value="Get all options" class="get_options"/>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script>
  var array_values = [];
  $(".get_options").click( function (){

  var values = $.map($('#selectBox option.get_this'), function(ele) {

   array_values.push(ele.value);
});

  console.log(array_values);
  });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you also could take the `innerHTML` value, but yes, this is the right answer

Comment: but  how to get middle value instead of using 'ele.value' because sometimes value will be like this     text1   3   text1   ,text2    4    ,text2

Comment: @Artem Kobets  but how to get middle value instead of using 'ele.value' because sometimes value will be like this text1 3 text1 ,text2 4 ,text2

Comment: @Anonymous depends on what the actual text can be. You can retrieve ele.textContent and filter it through string manipulations such as [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), or [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)